# Adding an NSManagedObject to an NSMutableArray via didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a Core Data project set up, I've got an `NSFetchedResultsController` working properly, the `NSPredicates` works properly, and now I'm onto doing something useful with the data displayed on the screen.

Right now, I have UITableViewCellAccessory working properly to toggle checked/unchecked cells, but I'm returning a nil when I try to add `selectedManagedObject` to `myArrayOfManagedObjects` via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

What is the proper way add/remove an `NSManagedObject` to an `NSMutableArray` via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Here are the relevant properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject *selectedManagedObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArrayOfManagedObjects;
```

Here's my `viewDidLoad` where the array I want to dump `NSManagedObject's is instantiated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Standard Core Data Setup Stuff

    // Instantiate a list to store myArrayOfManagedObjects
    self.myArrayOfManagedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Here's my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSManagedObject *selectedManagedObject = self.selectedManagedObject;

        // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
        // TODO: add the object to the array
        if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
            // ** My problem lives here
            [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects insertObject:self.selectedManagedObject atIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Added %@ to myArrayOfManagedObjectsArray", selectedManagedObject.myObjectDescription);
            NSLog(@"myArrayOfManagedObjects contains %@", self.myArrayOfManagedObjects);
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        } else {
            [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            // ** My problem lives here
            [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"Removed %@ from myArrayOfManagedObjectsArray", selectedManagedObject.myObjectDescription);
            NSLog(@"myArrayOfManagedObjects contains %@", self.myArrayOfManagedObjects);
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

**Update: Problem Solved**

In case it wasn't clear, the stuff on my `tableView` is from a `fetchedResultsController`. My task was to add items from that to a separate `NSMutableArray` that I'm going to save.  Here's what got it working:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ** Problem Solved: I needed to tell the compiler where my selectedManagedObject was
    self.selectedManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set the checkmark accessory for the selected row.
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects addObject:self.selectedManagedObject];
        NSLog(@"Added **%@** to myArrayOfManagedObjects", self.selectedManagedObject.description);
        NSLog(@"myArrayOfManagedObjects contains %lu objects", (unsigned long)[self.myArrayOfManagedObjects count]);
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    } else {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects removeObject:self.selectedManagedObject];
        NSLog(@"Removed **%@** from myManagedObjectArray", self.selectedManagedObject.description);
        NSLog(@"myArrayOfManagedObjects contains %lu objects", (unsigned long)[self.myArrayOfManagedObjects count]);
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the logic you put in place. Or maybe I don't understand it.

You have an array containing all your objects currently displayed, right? This is `self.myArrayofManagedObjects`. I assume you're filling it somewhere else, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question.

Then you select and do this :

```
NSManagedObject *selectedManagedObject = self.selectedManagedObject;
```

means (as you definitely know) that your newly instantiated `NSManagedObject` is now the same as the one from your .h, which is, from what I can see, not instantiated.

So you're pretty much playing with `nil` every line following that one.

What you should probably do is this :

```
NSManagedObject *selectedManagedObject = [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

or

```
self.selectedManagedObject = [self.myArrayOfManagedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now you have a reference to the right object in your array of objects and can start manipulating it.

From what I can see you would like to add or remove that object to some array, so you simply to add or remove that reference to your new array.

```
[myArray addObject:OBJECT];
[myArray removeObject:OBJECT];
```

Since they're references, they'll find it.

If you're modifying the data of the same array that built your tableview, then you have to call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to see your newly updated tableview

Comment: The `tableView` displays stuff from the `fetchedResultsController`. I'm trying to select `NSManagedObject`s from the `tableView` and add/remove them to/from an `NSMutableArray` to save to disk.

Your solution got me a little further, but I got this error:
` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'`

Comment: Well that seems pretty clear, you're trying to interact at index 1 in an array that is empty.

When you mean save to disk, you mean write a file or simply save your context/persistent store?

Comment: I plan to save the `NSMutableArray` of `selectedManagedObjects` and retrieve them on a different `viewController`.

Comment: Okay so you just need them in another array, what you need to do is very simple : 
On didSelect, check if the object is already in the array. If yes, remove it, if not ,add it.
I suggest you use  breakpoints to see if they add to the array properly and if they remove like they should.
When did the exception occur exactly? Also, could you edit your post with the new code AND a comment on the line that crashed? Notify me here when you did all that with new information :)

Comment: I got it figured out with your help and that of Aneeq Anwar. I put in the `addObject` portion AND I changed my selectedManagedObject to this: `    self.selectedManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]` It works flawlessly. Thank you both.

Comment: SO helped me many times, glad I could return the favour ! Keep coding :)

Answer (score 1):

For adding object in mutable array:

```
[self.myArrayOfManagedObjects addObject:obj];
```

For removing object from mutable array:

```
[self.myArrayOfManagedObjects removeObject:obj];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I figured out what I needed to do to get the right "thing" selected with your help.